# EF Many-To-Many on single entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many

I have an issue to implement many-to-many relationship with same entities. Here's my class:

```
public class District
{
    [Key]
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public List<District> SubDistricts { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to have all districts within same table, and to have them correlated, many districts to many districts.

If I don't specify mappings, EF Code First acts as if it is one-to-many relationship.

I've tried to give directions to model builder, but it's not working:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<District>()
    .HasMany(d => d.SubDistricts)
    .WithMany(d => d.SubDistricts)
    .Map(mc => { mc.ToTable("DistrictLinks", "dbo");
                 mc.MapLeftKey("ParentId");
                 mc.MapRightKey("ChildId");
               });
```

Is there any way to do this with WF? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the `WithMany` overload which doesn't take a parameter:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<District>()
    .HasMany(d => d.SubDistricts)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(mc => { mc.ToTable("DistrictLinks", "dbo");
                 mc.MapLeftKey("ParentId");
                 mc.MapRightKey("ChildId");
               });
```

It is not possible that the same navigation property is start and end of an association at the same time. They either must be different or the end is "unvisible" and not exposed in the model - which is the case in your model.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works well, thank you! In the meanwhile, I've came up with another way to resolve issue. Basically I've created two navigational properties in class:

```
public List<District> ChildDistricts { get; set; }
public List<District> ParentDistricts { get; set; }
```

so my mapping looks like this now:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<District>()
    .HasMany(d => d.ParentDistricts)
    .WithMany(d => d.ChildDistricts)
    .Map(mc => { mc.ToTable("DistrictLinks", "dbo");
                 mc.MapLeftKey("ParentId");
                 mc.MapRightKey("ChildId");
               });
```

As a result, I get exactly the same kind of table in SQL Server, but I believe I can navigate better like this. I actually forgot to mention that hierarchy is of importance here as well,  not just links between districts.

Thank you once again :)

Comment: Yes, that's possible as well :)